# Не работает скрипт, не могу отправить запрос перехода на websocket серверу

Tags: javascript, сервер, websocket

Реализую свой http сервер, пытаюсь сделать поддержку протокола веб соккет. Хочу посмотреть, какие заголовки приходят на сервер, чтоб понять, как их правильно обрабатывать. Я не js-сер и не могу написать нормальный код, который откроет соединение. Я взял пример с интернета

```
 window.onload = function(){
         var socket = new WebSocket("http://localhost:8000/");
         var status = document.querySelector("#status");
         console.log(socket)



        socket.onopen = function() {
          status.innerHTML = "cоединение установлено<br>";
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
          if (event.wasClean) {
            status.innerHTML = 'cоединение закрыто';
          } else {
            status.innerHTML = 'соединения как-то закрыто';
          }
          status.innerHTML += '<br>код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason;
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
          let message = JSON.parse(event.data);
          status.innerHTML += `пришли данные: <b>${message.name}</b>: ${message.msg}<br>`;
        };

        socket.onerror = function(event) {
           status.innerHTML = "ошибка " + event.message;
        };
        document.forms["messages"].onsubmit = function(){
            let message = {
                 name:this.fname.value,
                 msg: this.msg.value
            }
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            return false;
        }

    }
```

встроил этот код в html страничку. Он не работает, на сервер ничего не приходит. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту пробелму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы открыть WebSocket нужно делать запрос не по `http` протоколу, а по `ws`.
Исправьте вторую строку на:

```
  var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/");
```

Comment: все равно ничего не приходит

Comment: Тогда давайте начнем с того, высвечивает ли на фронте, что соединение установлено?

Comment: Не должно высвечиваться,я жду, пока клиент просто отправит запрос на переключение протокола, но на сервер ничего не приходит

Comment: На каком порте и хосте работает WS бекенд?

Comment: на локальной машине, порт 8000

Comment: Попробуй в консоле браузера исполнить этот кусок кода ```new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/");```

Comment: http и websocket могут же работать на одном порту через 1 tsp соккет?

Comment: По идее им нужны отдельные TCP. Попробуй на бекенде слушать WS на 8081

Comment: VM35:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response. Приходит вот такая ошибка, но почему запрос даже не приходит?

Comment: Ты используешь нативные сокеты или socket.io?

Comment: Бэк сокетов на чем? Если workerman, то запускай в debug режиме и смотри что происходит при запуске, запускается ли вообще и что происходит при коннекте...